# Arrivée à l’échéance de la vulgarité

Tags: vocabulaire

This is from Proust:

> Mais si le photographe avait été écarté de la représentation du chef-d’œuvre ou de la nature et remplacé par un grand artiste, il reprenait ses droits pour reproduire cette interprétation même. **Arrivée à l’échéance de la vulgarité,** ma grand’mère tâchait de la reculer encore.

Looking at the dictionary for [échéance](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance) it is always has something to do with time.  So the question here is why does Proust seem to use it with the sense of 'threshold'.  For me to arrive at the 'threshold' of vulgarity would be to do something almost vulgar but not quite.

Comment: That's a tough one. Even as a native speaker it's hard to interpret. It's more of a literature analysis question than a language one. Good question though!

Comment: @TeleportingGoat It's easier to understand with more context. A little earlier is written: *Mais au moment d’en faire l’emplette, et bien que la chose représentée eût une valeur esthétique, elle trouvait que la vulgarité, l’utilité reprenaient trop vite leur place dans le mode mécanique de représentation, la photographie.*

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "échéance of vulgarity" should be interpreted as "point where a first degree of vulgarity is manifest" or "threshold" in other words. This word should be taken as having a meaning "by extension" or figurative, as reckoned by some people.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance)) − P. ext. Date à laquelle un événement doit arriver, qui marque la fin d'un délai.
> • L'échéance éloignée de la récolte;
> • les échéances de l'avenir. L'échéance du débarquement étant maintenant imminente (De Gaulle, Mém. guerre,1956, p. 220):

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance)) (Sens figuré)
> • Nous verrons bien la valeur de vos promesses quand elles seront arrivées à échéance.

As interpreted from the TLFi, the word means "time when something occurs" (harvest) ; as interpreted from the Wiktionnary, there is an added extrapolation: in this example it is "the time when it will be proper to turn promisses into acts".

> Elle eût aimé que
> j’eusse dans ma chambre des photographies des monuments ou des
> paysages les plus beaux. Mais au moment d’en faire l’emplette, et bien
> que la chose représentée eût une valeur esthétique, elle trouvait que la
> vulgarité, l’utilité reprenaient trop vite leur place dans le mode
> mécanique de représentation, la photographie. Elle essayait de ruser
> et, sinon d’éliminer entièrement la banalité commerciale, du moins de
> la réduire, d’y substituer, pour la plus grande partie, de l’art encore,
> d’y introduire comme plusieurs « épaisseurs » d’art : au lieu de
> photographies de la Cathédrale de Chartres, des Grandes Eaux de
> Saint-Cloud, du Vésuve, elle se renseignait auprès de Swann si quelque
> grand peintre ne les avait pas représentés, et préférait me donner des
> photographies de la Cathédrale de Chartres par Corot, des Grandes
> Eaux de Saint-Cloud par Hubert Robert, du Vésuve par Turner, ce qui
> faisait un degré d’art de plus. Mais si le photographe avait été écarté
> de la représentation du chef-d’œuvre ou de la nature et remplacé par
> un grand artiste, il reprenait ses droits pour reproduire cette
> interprétation même. Arrivée à l’échéance de la vulgarité, ma
> grand’mère tâchait de la reculer encore. Elle demandait à Swann si
> l’œuvre n’avait pas été gravée, préférant, quand c’était possible, des
> gravures anciennes et ayant encore un intérêt au delà d’elles-mêmes,
> par exemple celles qui représentent un chef-d’œuvre dans un état où
> nous ne pouvons plus le voir aujourd’hui (comme la gravure de la Cène
> de Léonard avant sa dégradation, par Morgan).

According to his grandmother, photography is vulgar because it would be wanting in artistic qualities, those that a painter could supply, so when time came to buy photographies, instead of photographies of a particular place she would try to find photographies of paintings of the place; photography was then acceptable to her, but direct photography was tantamount to vulgarity. "Arrivée à l'échéance de la vulgarité" then means "When came the moment when no photographed painting was available", that is, "when time had come to buy a plain photography because there was nothing else", or, in other words "when  the only choice was vulgarity". Given this extremity, she would still refrain from buying plain photographies and she would try to find out if instead she could'nt find engravings of the paintings. In Proust's text there is another extrapolation to take into account, since "the time when vulgarity occurs" is meaningless.

Comment: Excellent.  All this makes very good sense.  Tanks (sic).